# how can i optimize the performance of this regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, optimization, performance

I'm using a regular expression to replace commas that are not contained by text qualifying quotes into tab spaces.
I'm running the regex on file content through a script task in SSIS. The file content is over 6000 lines long.
I saw an example of using a regex on file content that looked like this

```
String FileContent = ReadFile(FilePath, ErrInfo);        
Regex r = new Regex(@"(,)(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)");
FileContent = r.Replace(FileContent, "\t");
```

That replace can understandably take its sweet time on a decent sized file.

Is there a more efficient way to run this regex?
Would it be faster to read the file line by line and run the regex per line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the lookahead, which looks all the way to the end on each comman, resulting in O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity, which is noticeable on long inputs. You can get it done in a single pass by skipping over quotes while replacing:

```
Regex csvRegex = new Regex(@"
    (?<Quoted>
        ""                  # Open quotes
        (?:[^""]|"""")*     # not quotes, or two quotes (escaped)
        ""                  # Closing quotes
    )
    |                       # OR
    (?<Comma>,)             # A comma
    ",
RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
content = csvRegex.Replace(content,
                        match => match.Groups["Comma"].Success ? "\t" : match.Value);
```

Here we match free command and quoted strings. The `Replace` method takes a callback with a condition that checks if we found a comma or not, and replaced accordingly.

Comment: This looks interesting. However, the match.Value seems to be out of scope and cannot be used as a parameter in that call to Replace.

Comment: @towps - My bad - should have been a `:`.

Comment: The: `(?:[^"]|"")*` sub-expression can be significantly sped up by applying Friedl's unrolling-the-loop technique like so: `[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*`.

Comment: A callback (or _replacement delegate_ in .NET-speak), used here, is required to solve this problem using regex. +1

Answer (score 6):

It seems you're trying to convert comma separated values (CSV) into tab separated values (TSV).

In this case, you should try to find a CSV library instead and read the fields with that library (and convert them to TSV if necessary).

Alternatively, you can check whether each line has quotes and use a simpler method accordingly.

Comment: yeah you're probably right. the regex isn't infallible anyway so i can't guarantee that it will work the way i'd expect 100% of the time. 1 extra quote somewhere in the file can skew the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest optimization would be

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(,)(?=(?:[^""]|""[^""]*"")*$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"))
    Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(line, "\t"));
```

I haven't profiled it, but I wouldn't be surprised if the speedup was huge.

If that's not enough I suggest some manual labour:

```
var input = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("input.txt"));

char[] toMatch = ",\"".ToCharArray ();
string line;
while (null != (line = input.ReadLine()))
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(line);
    bool inquotes = false;

    for (int index=0; -1 != (index = line.IndexOfAny (toMatch, index)); index++)
    {
        bool isquote = (line[index] == '\"');
        inquotes = inquotes != isquote;

        if (!(isquote || inquotes))
            result[index] = '\t';
    }
    Console.WriteLine (result);
}
```

**PS:** I assumed `@"\t"` was a typo for `"\t"`, but perhaps it isn't :)

Comment: I'd be careful with the per-line match - CSV *might* contain newlines inside quotes (`1,2,"a\nb",4`), which cause some errors.

Comment: Yup. Similarly, the input _might_ contain a runaway string too, that would gobble up the entire remaining document if it went unchecked... YMMV; I'm basing this optimization on a few well-chosen assumptions. I'll leave it up the original poster to decide whether it suits his purpose

Comment: thanks, for sure that's helpful for what I was trying to do. It definitely sped things up.